# SQL get previous price and price changed

Tags: mysql, sql

Basically the excel look like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9GqU.png)

Now I've got current date & prices by myself:

```
SELECT p.item as Item, p.Cost as CurrentCost, p.CostDate as CurrentCostDate
FROM price_change.`question 3 data` p
inner join (
SELECT item, max(CostDate) as CurrentDate
FROM price_change.`question 3 data`
group by item
)pc on p.item = pc.item and p.CostDate = pc.CurrentDate
```

I wanted to get the most recent prices in every item, my thought is:
use `rank() over` to get the rank in every item order by date, then according to the rank to get the most recent price but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT item, CostDate,
FIRST_VALUE(Cost) OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY CostDate DESC)
FROM price_change.`question 3 data`
```

Comment: Cheers mate but this code only gets the current price, but not previous price

Comment: If you need the current price and also the previous price, you can extend to something like this: ````SELECT item, CostDate, FIRST_VALUE(Cost) OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY CostDate DESC),
FIRST_VALUE(Cost) OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY CostDate DESC RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
FROM price_change.`question 3 data`
````